# How to determine translation for dc.js bubbleOverlay points

Tags: dc.js

How can we find the translate values for the bubbleoverlay map? "Major Canadian City Crime Stats" example gives these options to the map:

```
        .point("Toronto", 364, 400)
        .point("Ottawa", 395.5, 383)
        .point("Vancouver", 40.5, 316)
        .point("Montreal", 417, 370)
        .point("Edmonton", 120, 299)
        .point("Saskatoon", 163, 322)
        .point("Winnipeg", 229, 345)
        .point("Calgary", 119, 329)
        .point("Quebec", 431, 351)
        .point("Halifax", 496, 367)  
        .point("St. John's", 553, 323)
        .point("Yukon", 44, 176)
        .point("Northwest Territories", 125, 195)
        .point("Nunavut", 273, 188)
```

You can see this code from http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/crime/index.html

How to determine these point options?

Thanks

Comment: Good question. Note it's just using an SVG backdrop rather than a "real" topoJson map, so those values may just have been estimated from the image rather than calculated. There is an open issue to convert it to a "real" map: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/476

Comment: Note there is also [dc.leaflet.js](https://github.com/yurukov/dc.leaflet.js), for a really comprehensive solution using leaflet for the maps.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I am new in this awesome world. Thank you for  your hard working .